# Existence of a specific linear combination of independent random variables (stochastic representation of the flexible skew normal)

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, skewness, skew-normal-distribution

Suppose to have two standard normal variables $X$ and $Y$.
I would like to find something  as

$Y= aR+\sum_{i=1}^k b_kC_k$ (1)

(k can be 1,2 or whatever) where $a,b_1, \dots , k$ are appropriate coefficients, $R,C_1, \dots ,C_k$ are independent random variables, $R=X-\alpha Y- \beta Y^3$, and each $C_k$ is (possible linear) combination of $X, Y$ and $Y^3$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are given coefficients.

Is this possible? Can someone help me?

In fact the question can be asked differently:

If we have two standard normal variables $X$ and $Y$, then

$Z=\delta |X|+\sqrt{1-\delta^2}Y, \delta \in [-1,1]$  (2)

is distributed as a skew normal in the sense of Azzalini. 
An extension of the skew normal is the flexible skew normal, http://stsda.kaust.edu.sa/Documents/2004.MG.SJS.pdf. I am wondering if for this distribution it is possible to find something as equation (2).

Comment: It appears that you could rephrase your question as "for given $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does there exist a vector $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $(1+\alpha) Y - X + \beta Y^3 = \mathbf{a} C$, where $C = \left[ X, Y, Y^3 \right]^T$."  Is that right?  If so, wouldn't $\mathbf{a} = \left[-1, 1+\alpha, \beta \right]$ (trivially?) do the trick?

Comment: Each element of $\mathbf{C}$ must be independent of each others and $R$, then $Y$ and $Y^3$ cannot be both in $\mathbf{C}$